# Async / Await chain hangs or deadlocks

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a Universal App that updates several objects from an internet source. In order to update the progress indicator and prevent duplicate requests I have the following logic.

On refresh button:

```
foreach (var package in Packages.Where(item => !item.Received)) 
{
    RefeshPackage(package);
}
```

Which calls RefreshPackage for each package in the list:

```
private async Task RefeshPackage(PackageModel package)
{
    if (Tasks.Contains(package.Id)) return;    
    Tasks.Add(package.Id);

    await DownloadAndUpdate(package);

    Tasks.Remove(package.Id);
    Refresh.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Which calls DownloadAndUpdate for each package:

```
private async Task DownloadAndUpdate(PackageModel package)
{
    var response = await webService.GetPackageStages(package.Id);
    if (response != null)
    {
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case 200:
                package.UpdateStages(response.Stages);
                break;

            case 500:
                //package doesn't exist or website down
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no network / timed out
    }
}
```

Which calls GetPackageStages for each package:

```
public async Task<ResponseData> GetPackageStages(string id)
{
    var requestUri = string.Concat(MyUri, id);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);

    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //process response
        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The hanging/deadlocking happens always in the last function, in the line:

```
await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
```

Sometimes it hangs here forever sometimes it works just fine. I've read a whole lot of other answers here regarding deadlocking and the common solutions are *using async/await all the way* (which I am already doing) or using *.ConfigureAwait(false)* also everywhere (which I already did with no success).

Is there something else I'm missing or should I structure my code a different way? I've ran out of ideas/solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `RefreshPackage` is an async method. Why aren't you doing anything with the resulting `Task` in the outer `foreach` loop? Even if you don't want to await it, at the very least you should observe errors on it (`.ContinueWith(, ...TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)`).

Comment: how would you know? You don't wait for the result of `RefeshPackage(package);`

Comment: Is it hangs or go to  //no network / timed out case?

Comment: Jeroen I marked it as async in order to use await inside. Should I mark it as void then if I don't use the result? Jodrell I know it hangs there because the breakpoint in the line immediately after doesn't get hit when it hangs (but when it works it does get hit). gabba it just hangs, no messages in output, nothing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert your solution worked, an exception was being swallowed and it affected the Task execution. If you can provide your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer `foreach` simply executes `RefeshPackage` without doing anything with its result. The problem with this "fire and forget" approach is that exceptions will go unobserved, so it becomes very hard to tell if your asynchronous code is actually executing correctly. Even if your task is supposed to handle exceptions, you should still observe it in case something isn't covered by your error handling strategy (using a catch-all handler in a task is just about as bad as using it anywhere else).

There are many ways to use the resulting `Task`. Which is appropriate depends on your circumstances. If your outer loop is itself `async`, it's sufficient to `await` the result (if it's synchronous, use `Task.Wait()`). This does mean the loop will not proceed until the task is complete; if you actually wanted to run all tasks in parallel, collect them in a `Task[]` and use `await Task.WhenAll()` (for synchronous code, use `Task.WaitAll()`).

If you want all tasks to run in parallel and don't care about any results, the least you can do is use `Task.ContinueWith()`, passing `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` to run logging code. This is the closest thing to "fire and forget" without discarding actual errors.

Once you have fixed that and can observe any errors of the asynchronous code, you can get to debugging the actual problems.